# PHP form upload 500kb limit

Tags: php, apache, wamp

Have a strange problem I can't figure out. Have a website with two forms on separate pages - both upload files to the server.

FormA can upload files of over 20MB. FormB can only upload files of up to 500KB. I've no idea why!

FormB used to be able to upload 30 images of around 300KB each in one go, but now it times out. The message I get after 60 seconds is "408 Request Timeout".  It was working until I started using GD to alter the image after upload, but now even with all of that removed, so the form literally uploads the file & does nothing else, it still times out.

I've even copied FormA over the top of FormB & still has the same issue.

Running on WAMP 2.5 on localhost.

### Edit

Have created a separate form on a completely separate website (same local server) and still getting the timeout when trying to upload either a single file of over 500KB or multiple files which total > 500KB.  Anything under that size is fine.  This is the form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input name="uploads" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload Images" />
</form>
```

I've tried it without editing PHP file upload sizes & also with using .htaccess to increase limits:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 60M
php_value max_file_uploads 50
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

Does this seem more like it's related to Apache, as there aren't any PHP errors (which I do get on FormA if I try to upload a massive file) and also if I put a phpinfo() at the top of the form, it doesn't ever show - just times out.

Comment: write this code above you php page **<?php ini_set('memory_limit','2048M'); ?>**

Comment: check `phpinfo()` what is the o/p

Comment: Bugfixer >> Done - no difference - still times out after exactly 60 seconds.

Comment: @ShowStopper >> assume you mean "output"? Unfortunately I can't get phpinfo to show any output after the form is submitted, as page just times out without displaying anything that's set to display via a PHP command.  Unless you want phpinfo prior on first page load (ie prior to form submission)?

Comment: just use this function in any of the page . just to get information of php

Comment: @ShowStopper - what info do you want to see from the phpinfo output?

Comment: I want to see the max execution time, upload size , post size , and no of file uploaded at a time

Comment: max_execution_time  = 180  /  upload_max_filesize = 50M  /  post_max_size = 60M  /  max_file_uploads = 50

Answer (score 0):

As files and other `<input>` fields are all part of the `post_max_size` then you should calculate `post_max_size` like this :-

```
post_max_size = (max_file_uploads*upload_max_filesize) + space for <input> fields
```

This allows you to upload the `max_file_uploads` of files allowed of up to the `upload_max_filesize` each.

As you are uploading 50 file I assume you are probably also sending 50+ other fields as well so the `+ space for <input> fields` will need to be a reasonable extra number of bytes.

Comment: I am in theory uploading 50 files at some point, but for now it doesn't even work when I upload 1 file! :(

Comment: Does your file upload code include tests on `$_FILES['files']['error']`? It should, and if it did it would probably give you at least a clue as to what was wrong! **Would be good to see how you process the upload**

Comment: Problem is - it's irrelevant what's in the process code, as it doesn't even get to that. If I put a phoinfo() as the very 1st line & upload a file that's < 500kb, it shows the info. But if the file(s) are > 500kb it doesn't ever show the info .... just waits & waits & waits for exactly 60 seconds, then I get the 408 Request Timeout.

I've subsequently set up a script which runs through a folder of images & converts (what I was orginally trying to do) & it all works fine - tested on around 900 images in one go.  Takes a while, but doesn't timeout.  So the issue seems to be POST related.

Comment: Have you looked in the `php error log` for any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer as such, but after testing on a non local web server (it worked fine) & then going back to this a few days later (after local PC restart) & it's now working as it should - so appears to have been a local issue which hopefully won't reoccur!